# Do I need to Dispose static objects which lives the whole life span of the application?

Tags: c#

Lets say I want to do some logging, the first thing I would do is opening up a `FileStream` to write to.

I would like to reuse the same stream for the application instead of opening and closing the stream for each log entry

This means the stream will live as long as the application.

something like

```
public static class Logger
{
    static StreamWriter SW;
}
```

Now the question is, do I need to make a close method which would `Dispose` SW and call it some where like `Window.Closed`

I feel GC would be able to do its job right and free SW when the application ends. But I want to make sure not doing so won't cause the application to hang in some special situations.

Comment: @GiladGreen the answer said all the resource will be free by the OS when app shuts down. But I want to know if not doing so could prevent the application from shutting down

Comment: IMHO, keeping a stream opened during the application lifetime is a bad idea it should be opened/closed only when really needed

Comment: @Sehnsucht wouldn't it be inefficient to close and reopen the stream though

Comment: @Steve Depends on the frequency. If you are doing slower than a write every .5 seconds the overhead likely will be unoticeable.

Comment: @Steve Also, don't re-invent the wheel. Other people have solved all the problems you run in to when writing a robust logger years ago and they offer the libraries for free. Just go use [Log4net or similar](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/).

Comment: @Steve all I/O operation are often "slow" operation so opening/closing a stream is almost always negligible compared to the actual stuff done with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the answer said all the resource will be free by the OS when app shuts down.

True, but just because a resource is freed does not mean it was freed in a clean manner.

You need to dispose of `StreamWriter` because it does not flush it's data immediately by default. If you do not Close/Dispose of it before your application is shut down the last bit of text will not be written out.

```
class Program
{
    static StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
    static void Main()
    {
        SW.Write("Test");
    }
}
```

The text file will not contain the word `Test` after running the above program.

If you added `SW.AutoFlush = true;` to the program you would be fine with not disposing of it. But you need to be aware of limitations like this when dealing with any class that implements `IDisposeable`